# Can't call function in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I get an error that says `this2.sampleFunction` is not an object , I have tried adding a constructor and all from previous solutions.

```
export default class Play extends React.Component {

  sampleFunction() {
    console.log('Hello'); 
  }

  anotherFunction() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.sampleFunction.bind(this)} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    <Deck
      anotherFunction={this.anotherFunction()}
    />
  }
}
```

EDIT : Here is the code in the deck component, it's just mainly a view tag

```
  render() {
return (
  <View>
    {this.props.anotherFunction()}
  </View>
);
}
```

Here is the image for the error : [image: error]

Comment: Your `onPress` listener is not correct. Do this instead: `onPress={this.sampleFunction.bind(this)}`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I'm using react-native-elements for the button if I remove the arrow than I still get the same error except now it says this.sampleFunction.bind is not an object

Comment: That means `this.sampleFunction` is undefined which implies either there's a typo or you are not showing the actual code.

Comment: No typo either :/

Comment: If that's not the case, then the only reason that I can think of is because `anotherFunction` is called without `this` set correctly. You will have to provide the actual code for us to determine the exact reason.

Comment: Hi, Please share the code of Deck component. if you want to pass a method to child component correct approach is  <Deck anotherFunction={this.anotherFunction.bind(this)} /> and call this function in child component. Right now an element is passed to Deck and not a function.

Comment: @VishuBhardwaj Added a little more information , hope it helps

Comment: Hi, I got the problem, It is same as I described in the comment. You are passing an element from Play to Deck but Deck expects a function. Please change render method of Play to render() {
    return (<Deck
      anotherFunction={this.anotherFunction.bind(this)}
    />);
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem, It is same as I described in the comment. You are passing an element from Play to Deck but Deck expects a function. Please change render method of Play to

```
render() {
    return (<Deck
      anotherFunction={this.anotherFunction.bind(this)}
    />);
}
```